# CLion has Run buttons greyed out or they dont work correctly

Tags: c++, configuration, ide, clion

I just got CLion today, and wanted to try it out. However, no matter what version I use, the following comes up when I open the run menu (I am on Windows):
Under "Run" in the top bar the normal Run and Debug are greyed out and I can only use the Run... / Debug... ones

In the top-right corner of the IDE the run button, the debug button and two other ones are also greyed out.

If I click on the run button or the debug button from the run menu (the ones with `...` on the end) there is a run option 0 called "edit configurations" which allows me to make a new run configuration.

So I tried to set up something that works, but I was unable to do so. I also could not find anything on the internet that I was able to understand, and every tutorial that I watched had already had it working.

Could someone please help me in an idiot-proof way?

Comment: Links rot, rendering your question completely worthless to future askers in the long run. Because of this, questions re required to contain all relevant information in the question itself. More immediate to your concerns, getting an answer, links to some unknown data at the other side of a hash are unlikely to be clicked by anyone smart enough to answer your question.

Comment: What type of project are you using with clion? Is it a cmake project?

Comment: thank you user4581301 for the tip, i took the links out and gave my best to describe them.

Comment: Avery3R firstly I'd like to be able to print out hello world and learn c++, but eventually my goal is to make a small game (probably 2d)

Answer (score 2):

**Minimal working sample (macOS)** - nothing fancy, just a good old `Hello, world!`

[image]

**Minimal working sample (Windows 10)** - nothing fancy, just a good old `Hello, world!`

**Install Visual Studio 2019**

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

**Configure toolchain**

[image]

**Run sample code**

[image]